# How to get the data from the table <7 days record and from <7 to 15 day of the record from data created?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

```
SELECT *
FROM [tablename]
WHERE Createdtime > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

i will get greater than 7 days record i need to get < 7 Days and from 7- 15 Days and 15-30 Days
it will help fully if you post an example and query thanks.

Comment: You want `AND` and the `<`, `>=` or `<=` operators. What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what YOU mean by "from 7-15 days".

Comment: `< 7 Days and from 7- 15 Days and 15-30 Days` - so really you just want everything that is 30 days old or less? And stop spamming your tags with irrelevant database engines. SQLCE is a very different (and obsolete) engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,CreatedDate,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 7 AND 15
```

using above query you can get records created between 20-Feb to 12-Feb-2020

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE Createdtime > DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()) and
      Createdtime < DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```